# What measures will the Olympic Committee take to avoid route leaks in Sports Climbing?

Tags: olympics, indoor-climbing

The Bouldering and Lead Climbing events at Tokyo 2020 (now 2021) will require professional routesetters to design routes for the athletes to climb. This creates the potential for those routes to be leaked to some athletes before the event.

I can't think of another sport where athletes could benefit so much from information being leaked before the event, so I was wondering what steps are being taken to deal with this new possible way in which countries could cheat.

Comment: A similar question from a different field: [How is secrecy maintained in movie production?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/111496/how-is-secrecy-maintained-in-movie-production) Many of the same points there will apply.

Comment: @PhilipKendall you are right that the career argument from that post applies here, but I believe the stakes are very different. There is neither money nor prestige to be gained by leaking the plot twist of an upcoming movie. The allure of sponsorships and bribes, on the other hand, has driven athletes and entire national teams to doping, match-fixing and other forms of cheating in the past.

Comment: There is definitely money to be made from leaking the plot twist of a movie, the more populist bits of the press will _definitely_ pay for that kind of thing.

Comment: @PhilipKendall true.